# Improve Python if conditional

Tags: python, if-statement, format, python-2.x, code-cleanup

How to improve the following if conditional in Python 3.6 to one line.

```
def run_cmd(beta: bool): {
  cmd = "cloud create {}".format(self.name)
  if beta:
    cmd = "cloud beta create {}".format(self.name)
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `if` statement since you are setting `beta` to `False` and there is nothing in your code that will change that.

Comment: Something like `cmd = "cloud beta create {}".format(self.name) if beta else "cloud create {}".format(self.name)`? That's assuming, of course, the value of `beta` could change.

Comment: Well in the same way they could just go for `cmd = "cloud create "` because beta is false and name is empty :) Bad question

Comment: if `beta` was not staticly fixed: `cmd = "cloud {}create {}".format("beta " if beta else "", self.name)`

Comment: OP, I'm afraid your question is currently somewhat confusing. It would probably be best to reformulate your question and clearly state what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I edited, it, i just declared beta as false to show it was a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following one liner will achieve it:

```
cmd = "cloud {}create {}".format("beta " if beta else "", name)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this:

```
cmd = "cloud{} create {}".format(["", " beta"][beta], self.name)
```

Comment: Is it really better? Much less readable. Not always converting things to one line make things better.

Comment: I prefer explicit stuff, so for me I would leave it as is in the original question. I like using the boolean as the index though. Neat.

Comment: better = more efficient ? I don't know. better = more readable ? I don't know too :) It depends... You even can write this `f"cloud {'beta ' if beta else ''}create {name}"` in Python3 (since you prefer the A if cond else B construction).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reduce the if statement:

```
name = ''
beta = True

cmd = "cloud beta create {}".format(name) if beta else "cloud create {}".format(name)
```